# IE proxy settings using python and webdriver

Tags: python, internet-explorer, proxy, webdriver

I am trying to set the proxy settings for internet explorer using selenium with python.

This is what i have done::

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "localhost:8080"

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "noProxy":None,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    "autodetect":False
}


driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER)
```

The above snippet is provided in the documentation but when i used it to set the proxy i got an exception that :: target machine actively refused the connection.

Can anyone help me in setting the proxy for IE .

My purpose is :: i have to set the proxy in IE , open IE and test some things and then revert back IE to normal .

I am using python and selenium webdriver.
How can i achieve this using them?

Comment: What version of the IEDriver are you using?

Comment: I am using selenium 2.26. It comes with iedriver . I am not using a separate IEDriverServer.  However i tried using that also . I got the same issue.

Comment: You need to be using version 2.34. The IEDriver doesnt even have proxy support until then.

Comment: @Arran :: thanQ Aran,

Comment: ThanQ Aran, But selenium 2.34 doesnt come with IE driver right? I think i have to download separate IEDriver server. Will it be possible to do this using older versions of selenium?

Comment: You will need to update IEDriver to the latest version. No, it does not come bundled with Selenium. It is available for download separately: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list  ...as you point out, older versions bundled it, later versions do not. If you want to have **any** chance of your proxy code working, then you'll need to upgrade to the latest version of Selenium & IEDriver.